# Change range element's step depending on it's value

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have this range element:

```
<input  type="range" 
        onchange= "calculate();"
        id="sumRange" 
        min="50000" 
        max="500000" 
        value="50000" 
        step= "50000"/>
```

I want its "step" to change depending on its value. For example, if the value is less than 200000 then step = 5000, if more than 200000 then step= 50000.

How can I do that? Do I create a function with simple "if" statements and make it run onchange of the range?

All example i've seen involve jQuery or something else, can i do this without...that?

Comment: you can also use oninput

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below, change the ranges as needed

```js
function calculate() {
  var input = document.getElementById('sumRange');
  var val = input.value;
  
  var newStep;
  if (val < 100000) {
    newStep = 10;
  } else if (val < 150000) {
    newStep = 20;
  } else if (val < 200000) {
    newStep = 30;
  } else if (val < 250000) {
    newStep = 40;
  } else {
    newStep = 50;
  }
  
  input.step = newStep;
}
```

```html
<input  type="range" 
        onchange= "calculate();"
        id="sumRange" 
        min="50000" 
        max="500000" 
        value="50000" 
        step= "50000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is what you can do in your calculate function, using jquery

```
  calculate = function() {
  if ($('#sumRange').attr('value') < 200000 ) {
     $('#sumRange').attr('step',5000);
  } else {
     $('#sumRange').attr('step',50000);
  }
```

Comment: Take the [2 Minute Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Pretty cool stuff going on here.

Comment: Thanks Dude will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sumRange = document.getElementById(“sumRange”);
sumRange.oninput = function(){
  var value = this.value;
  if (value > 20000) {
     this.step = 50000;
 } else {
     this.step=5000;
  }
```

Comment: Please take the time to format the code and make your answers neat. If everyone posted as sloppily as you just did this site would be a mess. I fixed it.

Comment: Also code only and link-only answers are inappropriate on this site, please provide some explanation for what your fix does. In general people should not be forced to read every line of every example posted to try to figure out what they do. If there were 10 long answers, and only 2 of them worked, if everyone had to study all 10 to figure out most of them were no good it would be a huge waste of time, so please add a description.

Comment: Also look at the answer that was accepted and got the up-votes. What did they do differently from you?